# Update Youtube thumbnail posted on Facebook

Tags: facebook, youtube

My problem is the **facebook** not update my **youtube** thumbnail even if I use the `linter/debugger` to force it to update.

Here is my step,

1. I post a video on **youtube** **[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgVBLVvLDWA)**, with `thumbnail1`.
2. I post the link on **facebook**, everything seems to be correct, the `thumbnail1` is posted
3. I changed the thumbnail to `thumbnail2`.
4. Force facebook to update using linter/debugger.
5. Post of the link in (1) on Facebook, the thumbnail is still the old one.

I tried to debug it and it seems that Facebook cached the old image. So I tries to force it to update this image, at this url :

http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VgVBLVvLDWA/maxresdefault.jpg

and it doesn't work...
Anyone has any clues ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looking at the URL debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DVgVBLVvLDWA) the thumbnail seems to be the one you want (http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VgVBLVvLDWA/maxresdefault.jpg). Is that not correct?

Comment: Yes, it is now correct. I don't exactly know why, I just change the image to another one(this current one) then it works :\